# Using nmake in Visual Studio 2012 qpOASES

Tags: nmake

I'm trying to use nmake in Visual Studio 2012. Called me this error U1001: syntax error: Illegal character '{' in macro Stop.

My command is "nmake make.mk". Where is my mistake?

Thanks for reply

Library is qpOASES 3.1
The contents of the file "make.mk" is:

```
##  This file is part of qpOASES.
##
##  qpOASES -- An Implementation of the Online Active Set Strategy.
##  Copyright (C) 2007-2014 by Hans Joachim Ferreau, Andreas Potschka,
##  Christian Kirches et al. All rights reserved.
##
##  qpOASES is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
##  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
##  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
##  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
##
##  qpOASES is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
##  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
##  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
##  See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
##
##  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
##  License along with qpOASES; if not, write to the Free Software
##  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
##



##
##  Filename:  make.mk
##  Author:    Hans Joachim Ferreau, Andreas Potschka, Christian Kirches
##  Version:   3.0
##  Date:      2007-2014
##


TOP = $(realpath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

#include ${TOP}/make_linux.mk
#include ${TOP}/make_cygwin.mk
include ${TOP}/make_windows.mk
#include ${TOP}/make_osx.mk
```

make_windows:

```
##
##  This file is part of qpOASES.
##
##  qpOASES -- An Implementation of the Online Active Set Strategy.
##  Copyright (C) 2007-2014 by Hans Joachim Ferreau, Andreas Potschka,
##  Christian Kirches et al. All rights reserved.
##
##  qpOASES is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
##  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
##  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
##  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
##
##  qpOASES is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
##  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
##  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
##  See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
##
##  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
##  License along with qpOASES; if not, write to the Free Software
##  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
##



##
##  Filename:  make_windows.mk
##  Author:    Hans Joachim Ferreau, Andreas Potschka, Christian Kirches
##  Version:   3.0
##  Date:      2007-2014
##


##
##  definitions for compiling with Visual Studio under Windows
##


################################################################################
# user configuration

# include directories, relative
IDIR =   ${TOP}/include
SRCDIR = ${TOP}/src
BINDIR = ${TOP}/bin

# Matlab include directory (ADAPT TO YOUR LOCAL SETTINGS!)
#MATLAB_IDIR   = ${HOME}/Programs/matlab/extern/include/
MATLAB_IDIR = /usr/local/matlab/extern/include/
MATLAB_LIBDIR = /usr/local/matlab/bin/glnxa64/


# system or replacement BLAS/LAPACK
REPLACE_LINALG = 1

ifeq ($(REPLACE_LINALG), 1)
    LIB_BLAS =   ${SRCDIR}/BLASReplacement.o
    LIB_LAPACK = ${SRCDIR}/LAPACKReplacement.o
else
    LIB_BLAS =   /usr/lib/libblas.so
    LIB_LAPACK = /usr/lib/liblapack.so
endif


################################################################################
# do not touch this

CPP = cl
AR  = ar
RM  = rm
F77 = gfortran
ECHO = echo
CD = cd
CP = copy

# file extensions
OBJEXT = obj
LIBEXT = lib
DLLEXT = so
EXE = .exe
MEXOCTEXT = mex
DEF_TARGET = 
SHARED = /LD

# 32 or 64 depending on target platform
BITS = $(shell getconf LONG_BIT)

# decide on MEX interface extension
ifeq ($(BITS), 32)
    MEXEXT = mexglx
else
    MEXEXT = mexa64
endif

CPPFLAGS = -nologo -EHsc -DWIN32 -Dsnprintf=_snprintf
#-g -D__DEBUG__ -D__NO_COPYRIGHT__ -D__SUPPRESSANYOUTPUT__

FFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fPIC -DWIN32 -Wno-uninitialized
#        -g

# libraries to link against when building qpOASES .so files
LINK_LIBRARIES = ${LIB_LAPACK} ${LIB_BLAS}
LINK_LIBRARIES_AW = ${LIB_LAPACK} ${LIB_BLAS} -lm -lgfortran -lhsl_ma57 -lfakemetis

# how to link against the qpOASES shared library
QPOASES_LINK = /I${BINDIR} /WL /link ${BINDIR}/libqpOASES.lib
QPOASES_AW_LINK = /I${BINDIR} /WL /link ${BINDIR}/libqpOASES_aw.lib

# link dependencies when creating executables
LINK_DEPENDS = ${LIB_LAPACK} ${LIB_BLAS} ${BINDIR}/libqpOASES.${LIBEXT} ${BINDIR}/libqpOASES.${DLLEXT}


##
##  end of file
##
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `make.mk` is for linux. The file `make_windows.mk` (as it says in the comments within it) is for windows using Visual Studio.

You would invoke `nmake` to use the correct makefile with the command:

```
nmake /f make_windows.mk
```

Does it not explain this in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the manual:

- make_linux.mk, the default choice, for compiling under Linux,
- make_cygwin.mk for compiling under Windows using Cygwin,
- make_windows.mk for compiling under Windows using Microsoft Visual
  Studio,
- make_osx.mk for compiling under Mac OS X.